# Type hinting an instance of a nested class

Tags: python, inheritance, inner-classes, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a class structure that looks something like this:

```py
class Base:
    class Nested:
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.nestedInstance = self.Nested()
```

where subclasses of `Base` each have their own `Nested` class extending the original, like this:

```py
class Sub(Base):
    class Nested(Base.Nested):
        pass
```

This works perfectly, and instances of `Sub` have their `nestedInstance` attributes set to instances of `Sub.Nested`.

However, in my IDE the `nestedInstance` attribute is always treated as an instance of `Base.Nested`, not the inherited `Sub.Nested`. How can I make it so that `nestedInstance` will be inferred to be `Sub.Nested` rather than `Base.Nested`? (Without having to add extra code to every subclass; preferably, this would all be done in `Base`.)

(By the way, I'm aware that this is an odd structure, and I can go into detail about why I chose it if necessary, but I think it's pretty elegant for my situation, and I'm hoping there's a solution to this problem.)

Comment: Based on your code, `type(Sub().nestedInstance)` returns `<class '__main__.Sub.Nested'>`. What do you get on your side?

Comment: "However, the nestedInstance attribute always gets type-hinted as an instance of Base.Nested," What? What does that mean *exactly*? zyou haven't actually *type hinted anything*, there are no type hints in your code, so it isn't really clear

Comment: @msamsami @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry for the lack of clarification - I meant that my IDE (specifically vscode) always treats `nestedInstance` as an instance of `Base.Nested`. The code all works.

Comment: All instances of `Base` must accept any `Base.Nested` as the value of `nestedInstance` according to the Liskov substitution principle, so what your IDE is doing is correct and what you want it to do is wrong.

Comment: @zvone Ah, I missed that, thanks! Looks like I might have to look for another way to go about this.

Comment: @zvone This is a false dichotomy. The IDE is correctly inferring the type based on the first assignment to the `nestedInstance` attribute. But this does **not** mean that what OP is _trying_ to achieve will necessarily violate the LSP. It is just that the way the code is _now_ allows no other inference for the type checker. The question was whether it was _possible_ to make the type checker infer `nestedInstance` differently. And there are loads of different ways to do that, which are all correct, albeit with varying levels of verbosity.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I **don't** think this is a weird class structure. There are loads of reputable libraries/frameworks making use of nested classes in a similar fashion. Examples that come to mind immediately are `Pydantic` with its inner `Config`, as well as `Django` with their `Meta` inside the model class.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg In this code, it would be invalid to change the type of `nestedInstance` in the `Sub` class. Think of a function which takes a `Base` object as an argument and assigns a `Base.Nested` instance to its `nestedInstance` attribute. This should be valid, even if a `Sub` instance is passed to that function, because `Sub` inherits from `Base`. Therefore, `Sub.nestedInstance` cannot have `Sub.Nested` as its type. It would be, however, different, if the attribute was read-only...

Comment: @zvone You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree with the statement that you were trying to violate the Liskov substitution principle. You were merely looking for a way to let a static type checker infer the type of `nested_instance` for classes inheriting from `Base` to be their respective `Nested` class. Obviously this wasn't possible with the code you had; otherwise there would be no question.

There actually is a way to minimize repetition and accomplish what you want.

---

### Generics to the rescue!

You can define your `Base` class as generic over a type variable with the upper bound of `Base.Nested`. When you define `Sub` as a subclass `Base`, you provide a reference to `Sub.Nested` as the concrete type argument. Here is the setup:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, cast


N = TypeVar("N", bound="Base.Nested")


class Base(Generic[N]):
    nested_instance: N

    class Nested:
        pass

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.nested_instance = cast(N, self.Nested())


class Sub(Base["Sub.Nested"]):
    class Nested(Base.Nested):
        pass
```

This is actually all you need. For more info about generics I recommend the relevant section of [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics). A few things to note:

##### Why do we need the `bound`?

If we were to just use `N = TypeVar("N")`, the type checker would have no problem if we wanted do define a subclass like this:

```py
class Broken(Base[int]):
    class Nested(Base.Nested):
        pass
```

But this would be a problem since now the `nested_instance` attribute would be expected to be of the type `int`, which is not what we want. That upper bound on `N` will prevent this causing `mypy` to complain:

```
error: Type argument "int" of "Base" must be a subtype of "Nested"  [type-var]
```

##### Why explicitly declare `nested_instance`?

The whole point of making a class generic is to **bind** some type variable (like `N`) to it and then indicate that *some* associated type inside that class is in fact `N` (or even multiple). We essentially tell the type checker to expect `nested_instance` to always be of the type `N`, which must be provided, whenever `Base` is used to annotate something.

However, now the type checker will always complain, if we ever omit the type argument for `Base` and tried an annotation like this: `x: Base`. Again, `mypy` would tell us:

```
error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Base"  [type-arg]
```

This may be the only "downside" to the use of generics in this fashion.

##### Why [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)?

The problem is that inside `Base`, the `nested_instance` attribute is declared as a *generic* type `N`, whereas in `Base.__init__`, we assign an instance of the *specific* type `Base.Nested`. Even though it may seem like this should work, it does not. Omitting the `cast` call results in the following `mypy` error:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Nested", variable has type "N")  [assignment]
```

##### Are the quotes necessary?

Yes, and importing `__future__.annotations` does not help here. I am not entirely sure why that is, but I believe in case of the `Base[...]` usage the reason is that [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__) is actually called and you cannot provide `Sub.Nested` to it because it is not even defined at that point.

---

### Full working example

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, cast


N = TypeVar("N", bound="Base.Nested")


class Base(Generic[N]):
    nested_instance: N

    class Nested:
        pass

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.nested_instance = cast(N, self.Nested())


class Sub(Base["Sub.Nested"]):
    class Nested(Base.Nested):
        pass


def get_nested(obj: Base[N]) -> N:
    return obj.nested_instance


def assert_instance_of_nested(nested_obj: N, cls: type[Base[N]]) -> None:
    assert isinstance(nested_obj, cls.Nested)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub = Sub()
    nested = get_nested(sub)
    assert_instance_of_nested(nested, Sub)
```

This script works "as is" and `mypy` is perfectly happy with it.

The two functions are just for demonstration purposes, so that you see how you could leverage the generic `Base`.

---

### Additional sanity checks

To assure you even more, you can for example add `reveal_type(sub.nested_instance)` at the bottom and `mypy` will tell you:

```
note: Revealed type is "[...].Sub.Nested"
```

This is what we wanted.

If we declare a new subclass

```py
class AnotherSub(Base["AnotherSub.Nested"]):
    class Nested(Base.Nested):
        pass
```

and try this

```py
a: AnotherSub.Nested
a = Sub().nested_instance
```

we are again correctly reprimanded by `mypy`:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "[...].Sub.Nested", variable has type "[...].AnotherSub.Nested")  [assignment]
```

---

Hope this helps.

### PS

To be clear, you can still inherit from `Base` *without* specifying the type argument. This has no runtime implications either way. It's just that a strict type checker will complain about it because it is generic, just as it would complain if you annotate something with `list` without specifying the type argument. (Yes, `list` is generic.)

Also, whether or not your IDE actually infers this correctly of course depends on how consistent their internal type checker is with the typing rules in Python. PyCharm for example seems to deal with this setup as expected.

Comment: Oh wow, this fixes everything! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It gets typed as `Base.Nested` because that's what's in scope at initialisation. If you want to declare that `nestedInstance` is actually something else, then you'll probably need to actually type-hint it.

```
class Sub(Base):
    class Nested(Base.Nested):
        pass
    
    nestedInstance: Nested
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. I didn't want to do this because it would require adding code to every subclass, but if it's the only option I'll take it (though now I might go in a whole new direction since I've learned this is a violation of the LSP).